# QGIS Query Editor define variable

Tags: qgis, query, expression, qgis-variable

I am relatively new to QGIS. I use conditional formatting for various problems. In the qgis query editor, I would like to define a string variable for further usage, so I wouldn't have to retype the column name countles times.

Example: 
`A = 'B'` -- doesn't work

```
CASE 
    WHEN A LIKE   '<1,25'  THEN  color_rgb(1,2,3) 
END
-- A should be a column name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a layer variable as it's explain in [Nyalldawson blog](http://nyalldawson.net/2015/12/exploring-variables-in-qgis-pt-3-layer-level-variables/).
Then use the variable name with @ decorator in Calculator.

For exemple  :

1. Let's define the `column_name` variable in `layer properties > variables` panel to a real column name of your layer.

[image]

2. Then in Calculator I set the conditional code with this new variable (like @Chrisl show in his answer).

[image]

For your next layers you have to create and define again the variable in layer properties but only once in this place.
[image]

As you can see in your calculator when you  use the exact same code as the precedent one, the variable change the value :

[image]

### Why use layer variable than Global or Project variable ?

Because in you case you can define once the column_name variable and keep it as long as you want even if you define in another layer the same column_name variable.
If you use a project or global variable, the variable is define for all your layers but you need to redefine the value each time you need to perform your code (not recommended in your case)

Answer (score 1):

You can reference the column by using the `@` operator. So in your example:

```
CASE WHEN @A LIKE '<1,25' THEN color_rgb(1,2,3) END
```

Comment: Thanks, that is nice, it also works with double quotes. But I want to define and store the column name in the script. So I wouldn't have to retype @A all over.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was double quotes. 
A solution could be:

```
CASE WHEN "A" LIKE '<1,25' THEN color_rgb(1,2,3) END
```

Comment: this doesn't help you to define a column as a variable

Comment: True, actually.

Comment: did you try my answer？